# EF 2.1 Core IEntityTypeConfiguration Add default value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 2.1 to create a database.  I am able to set the default value of a column like

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    ....
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        ....
         modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.LastLoginDateTime).HasDefaultValueSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()");
    }
    ....
}
```

However, when I try to use the `IEntityTypeConfiguration` to set the default value, I get the build an error message (printed in the code below). I understand that the `HasDefaultValueSql()` is not available in `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>`.

How can I work around with that limitation?  By the way, I followed the Scott Sauber in his 'Customizing EF Core 2.0+ Entity/Table Mapping with IEntityTypeConfiguration - Sept 11, 2017) to create my `SchoolContext`.

https://scottsauber.com/2017/09/11/customizing-ef-core-2-0-with-ientitytypeconfiguration/

My code:

```
public class StudentConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure (EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
        ....
        // Error    CS1061  'PropertyBuilder<DateTime>' does
        // not contain a definition for 'HasDefaultValueSql' 
        // and no extension method 'HasDefaultValueSql' 
        // accepting a first argument of Type 'PropertyBuilder<DateTime>' 
        // could be found (are you missing a using directive
        // or an assembly reference?) 
        // Data C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\School\Data\EFClasses
        // \Configurations\StudentConfig.cs 22  Active

        builder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.RecIn).HasDefaultValueSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()");
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `builder` parameter type of the `Configure` method is `EntityTypeBuilder<T>`, and is exactly the same returned by `ModelBuilder.Entity<T>` method.

So when using `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`, you should use `builder` directly (w/o `Entity<T>()` call which is for `ModelBuilder`):

```
public class StudentConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(s => s.LastLoginDateTime).HasDefaultValueSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()");
    }
}
```

Btw, the `ModelBuilder.Entity<T>()` method has overload with `Action<EntityTypeBuilder<T>` argument which can be uses in a similar fashion:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>(builder =>
{
    builder.Property(s => s.LastLoginDateTime).HasDefaultValueSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()");
});
```

**Update:** Please note that `HasDefaultValueSql` is extension method defined in `RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions` class from [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) *assembly*, so make sure your project is referencing it.

Comment: Ivan,   if I understand correctly, the codes in public class StudentConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student> {…} mentioned earlier are correct.  However, there is no 'HasDefaultValueSql' in the methods or functions list so there is a build error CS1061  'PropertyBuilder<DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'HasDefaultValueSql' and no extension method 'HasDefaultValueSql' accepting a first argument of Type 'PropertyBuilder<DateTime>'.  Did I misinterpret your answer or I am lost in some ways.

Comment: The incorrect code in your question was `builder.Entity<Student>()`. Once you use `builder.Property(..)` you should have access to the same methods as in `OnModelCreating`, including the `HasDefaultValueSql`.

Comment: Are you still getting compiler error? Note that many EF Core methods are extension methods, which come from different assemblies. For this particular one make sure you reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly. Although the same is needed for the code inside `OnModelCreating` you said is working.

Comment: It's my fault.  You are right the builder.Entity<Student>().Property… in public class StudentConfig … should be builder.Property… I was checking on different version of the codes. The issue of my problem is missing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational in the project. I added it from NuGet.  There is no more compiler error. Thank you very much!